# Cannot stop excel from producing a rounded value based on a TRUE/FALSE condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm using the following formulas in range X30:X35:

- =IF(L$15=TRUE,E$5,E5)
- =IF(A$17="","",IF(L$15=TRUE,E$5,E6))
- =IF(A$17="","",IF(L$15=TRUE,E$5,E7))
- =IF(A$17="","",IF(L$15=TRUE,E$5,F5))
- =IF(A$17="","",IF(L$15=TRUE,E$5,F6))
- =IF(A$17="","",IF(L$15=TRUE,E$5,F7))

A17 contains a date. If there's no date in A7, the cell with the above formula (so X31:X35) is blank.

E5:E7 and F5:F7 are $ amounts inputted by the user.

L15 is a linked to a checkbox.

If L15=TRUE, E5:E7 and F5:F7 all display the $ amount from E5.

Here's my problem: when L15=TRUE, the amounts shown in X31:X35 are rounded.

Ex: If the amount in E5 is $100.50, and L15=TRUE, X31:X35 show $101.

X20:X25 are correctly formatted for $x.xx.

I've tried checking and rechecking the formatting, changing the formulas to &IF, and changing the order of the statements in the formulas.

I can't figure out what the problem is.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: The format of the cell cannot be affected by the formulas you posted. Do the cells react when you apply a different format? I assume you have formatted X30:X35, not X20:X25??

Comment: Sorry, I actually have several ranges I'm doing the same thing with. So it's both X20:X25 and X30:X35. The first cell in each range (X20, X30, etc) is working fine. Only the ones with "IF(A$17="",""," are rounding inexplicably.

Comment: My goto answer would be to use format painter and see if you can change the format. Also try a different format (e.g. scientific). If nothing changes, then perhaps the answer actually contains text data. Which leads me to my next guess. Perhaps the formatting is influenced by the text output of the true condition. Rearrange the if statement with a NOT so that you switch out the TRUE and FALSE statements. Also try formatting the numeric answer as deliberate text output using the TEXT function.

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED" in the title, we're not a forum - post an answer instead and mark it as accepted. This will make the solution easier to find for future visitors. I've rolled back your edit, you can still find it [in revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/1606863/revisions).

Comment: @user1247039,, plz [edit] your post & share some sample data,,, better the screen shot, help us to fix it !

Comment: I believe that this question should be closed as a ‘‘typo’’ problem.  @gronostaj: Do you really believe that there is anything here that will be valuable for future visitors?

Comment: @Scott Maybe, maybe not, but it's good to show the user how Superuser works in case they return later or want to participate in the community.

Comment: @Scott I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found some rogue conditional formatting. Cleared it out and now it works perfectly.